# Image from Media plugin in MVVM not dispalying

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using media plugin and i am not able to see the taken picture on my content page. While debugging the app i can see the path but the picture is not there I have tried to follow this solution, however still nothing. My Binding works fine for everything. Just I dont know how to get the imagem

```
 public MediaFile SelectedPhoto { get => _selectedPhoto; set { _selectedPhoto = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

 private async Task TakePicture()
        {
            await Permission();
            var imageSource = await DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShowActionSheet(AppResources.AlertPhoto, AppResources.AlertNewPhoto, AppResources.AlertGallery);
            if (imageSource == AppResources.AlertNewPhoto)
            {
                var imageFileName = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
                {
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg",
                    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                    SaveToAlbum = true
                });
                if (imageFileName == null)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(AppResources.AlertNoAcess);
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedPhoto = imageFileName;

                    //var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    //imageFileName.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    //imageFileName.Dispose();

                    //var incidentImage = new PostImage
                    //{
                    //    ImageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()
                    //};

                }
                

            }



<Image
                                    x:Name="Photo"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    Source="{Binding postViewModel.SelectedImage}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" />
```

Comment: The list if of fixed size, right? And each checkbox has a fixed index? So why not just use `userDecision[index] = result`? This way you could make the list (or use an array) into type bool..

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Hi, Is there a reason you are new-ing up the List each time?

Comment: Ok.. I'm not sure what `_parentCategoryID` is needed for, however for example, if you set `FilterAllItems` to true, then `GetUserDecision()` is called quite a few times. It seems to me, that instead of calling this function, just set the list elements directly. You can access them via their index.

Comment: @ Roland Deschain The parentcategory is later user for filter

Comment: @HagashenNaidu no there is not, i am not sure how else to do it. Sorry if my question is not clear

Comment: @RolandDeschain please see my updated question

Comment: Yes, the exception you get is most probably because no you don't instantiate the list. What you did before in your `GetUserDecision()` method with the line `List<int> userDecision = new List<int>();` was that you created your list new every time you called this function. Now, I guess, you don't create it at all, so you have to instantiate your list at the start of your program once.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I added that and still get an exception

Comment: and you still get an exception? What does it say?

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Comment: one moment, I'm trying to reproduce it...

Comment: Did you fill your List with initial values?
`public List<int> userDecision = new List<int>(){-1, 1, 2, 3, 4};`

Comment: No, i didnt, thank you so much for your time

Comment: Is there a way how to add in the list that the parent category = value?

Comment: You can simply set `_parentCategory` when you are setting the `userDecision` value?

Comment: @HagashenNaidu how??

Comment: After `userDecision[1] = 1` , you can do `_parentCategoryId = 1`